# Add same product with different color and price to the cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopping-cart

Now I can only add products using one price. In db I have two prices and different colors. It
needs to work like this, the first price is applied to the first color, the second price to all others colors

/src/app.js

```
const {getData} = require('./db/db');
const products = getData();
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

const onAdd = (product) => {
    const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist) {
      setCartItems(
          cartItems.map((x) =>
            x.id === product.id ? {...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1} : x
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, {...product, qty:1}])
    }
  };
```

/src/components/cart.jsx

```
function Cart({cartItems, onCheckout}) {
    const totalPrice = cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price[0] * c.qty, 0);
    return (
        <div className='cart_container'>
            <br/>
            <Button
                title={`${cartItems.length === 0 ? "Cart is empty" : "Cart" + '\n' + "Total Price: " + totalPrice} `}
                type={"checkout"}
                disable={cartItems.length === 0 ? true : false}
                onClick={onCheckout}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: did you mean to say ```the first price is applied to the first color, the second price to all other colors``` ?

Comment: @سعيد yeah, exactly

Comment: so what is the first color then ?

Answer (score 0):

you can go about doing it this way :

```
const firstColor = "grey" // for example 
const totalPrice = cartItems.reduce((a, c) =>{
 const price = c.color == firstColor ? c.price[0] : c.price[1]
 return a + price * c.qty : 
}, 0);
```

Comment: so yeah, it worked as an example, but how to take params: color and price, from db and connect them

Comment: cause in app.js I added checkbox to choose color and price, but still don't understand how to make this work properly

Comment: that's an other question my friend , there are a lot of ways you can achieve this and it depends on which db you're using and which backend , consider creating a separate question  .

Comment: ok ty, understand you